# Nested xpath: How do I use the result of an XPath expression as value?

Tags: xpath

I am having the following XML structure:

```
  <xml>
      <value>b</value>
      <objects>
        <object>
            <value>a</value>
        </object>
        <object>
            <value>b</value>
        </object>
      </objects>
  </xml>
```

What I want is to select the second object, based on the value in the xml.

This XPath works:

```
//xml/objects/object[value = 'b']
```

This XPath does not return results:

```
//xml/objects/object[value = //xml/value/text()]
```

Are nested XPath expressions not supported?

Answer (score 1):

They are, but the search within a predicate is always relative to the context you currently in.

Currently you start looking for an `<xml/>` element which is a child of `<object/>` and as there is none it will yield an empty result set.

Using `../` or `parent::*` you can go an axis step up to the parent and can select the required value:

```
//xml/objects/object[value = ../../value]
```